# libcuda.so.1 after installing CUDA drivers using conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed Tensorflow using `conda install tensorflow-gpu`. This also installed `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn`.

I can confirm that the files `libcudnn.so`, `libcudnn.so.7`, `libcudart.so` and `libcudart.so.9.0` are in my `anaconda3/envs/tf-env/lib/` folder.

However, `libcuda.so.1` is missing and when I try to import Tensorflow I get the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/envs/virtualnations/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Do you have current drivers/cuda version installed for your Nvidia card?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I had not. Solved the problem with `sudo apt get install nvidia-367-dev`